# Rails application runs from terminal but not from Netbeans - missing gem error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans, rubygems

Been trying to get my project up and running on an Ubuntu Virtual Box machine. Everything works fine from the terminal, but when I try to run my application from Netbeans I get the following error:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
/home/soroush/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:119:Warning: Gem::Dependency#version_requirements is deprecated and will be removed on or after August 2010.  Use #requirement
Missing these required gems:
  i18n  = 0.3.7

You're running:
  ruby 1.8.7.249 at /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  rubygems 1.3.7 at /home/soroush/.gem/ruby/1.8, /var/lib/gems/1.8

Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.
```

Running 'gem list' from the terminal shows that i DO have i18n installed. 
I've searched for answers but haven't really been able to find anything that correlates to my specific error.

Thanks in advance for any help! 
Regards,
Emil

Comment: Try running `gem environment` from the terminal and make sure the gem paths are the same as in NetBeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you right-click on your project, choose "Run / Debug Rake Task" and run the gems:install task mentioned above?

Alternatively you should right-click on the project, choose Properties, choose "Gems" in the sidebar and add the i18n gem there.  I had to do that for a project to get debugging working within netbeans, installing the correct gem using bundler from the command-line didn't do anything that NetBeans was picking up.

Comment: Thanks for your replys prodigitalson and alxp. 
It turns out the netbeans gem path was a different one than the one that showed up in the terminal. I ran the command, and switched netbeans gem path to GEM HOME to solve the problem. Thanks alot!